# Is the gun mention a subtitling error?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

I'm rewatching the Naruto Chuunin exams, and in the Crunchyroll subs in episode 40, when it's being explained by Zaku's arms blew out, the explanation mentions gun barrels. However, [as per this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8326/what-is-the-technology-level-in-the-naruto-universe/8327#8327), there are no guns in Naruto. I don't remember the Japanese word for gun or gun barrel, and my listening isn't good enough to tell what they're saying in this particular part. Is this simply a subtitling error, or do they actually use a gun analogy in this case? If they do use a gun analogy in the anime, do they use the same analogy in the Japanese manga--that is, do they canonically explain the result using a gun analogy despite the lack of guns in Naruto?

[image]

Comment: For reference, Dosu's explanation begins at 18:05 of the Crunchyroll stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the subtitles are okay. The Naruto manga does use a similar gun analogy. In chapter 70:

> ...Like a gun barrel when the path of a bullet is blocked, Zaku blew his arm off.

In the anime, I believe that the word that Dosu is using is [砲身](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%A0%B2%E8%BA%AB) (ほうしん), which translates to "gun barrel". For context, in that sentence, Dosu was saying something along the lines of:

> 砲身【ほうしん】であるザクの腕【うで】は暴発【ぼうはつ】し使【つか】い物【もの】になるなくなる

Comment: Technically, 砲身 refers to the barrels of an artillery cannon. Alternatively 銃身 refers to small arm gun barrels. The context seems to imply the former over the latter.

Answer (score -2):

Actually in the wave arc wean sakura gose to the store with the bridge builder theres a gun behind the counter. Or at least in the manga there is.

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/S6MW3K

Comment: Include all relevant details (volume, chapter, page, etc.) and do not put proofs to your argument as a comment. They should be on the main answer. Also, elaborate on your answer.